# Scraping data from Ajax Form Requests using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all the hospital data from this website.
https://www.german-hospital-directory.com/search/Bundesland/Baden-Wuerttemberg.html.

After looking at the requests,it makes a form request. And it is not accessible through ***scrapy shell***[image]

[image]

And in the response payload,it gives the entire html content. How do I extract each of the hospital data such as URL,NAME, IMAGE and traverse through all the hospitals. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to scrapy.

Do I need to use selenium or can I somehow achieve this using scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GET` your URL first (to receive cookies): https://www.german-hospital-directory.com/search/Bundesland/Baden-Wuerttemberg.html

But next you need to `GET` this URL https://www.german-hospital-directory.com/search/_files/main-search/Suchergebnis.jsf

Something like this:

```
start_urls = ['https://www.german-hospital-directory.com/search/Bundesland/Baden-Wuerttemberg.html']

def parse(self, response):

    yield scrapy.Request(

        url="https://www.german-hospital-directory.com/search/_files/main-search/Suchergebnis.jsf",
        callback=self.parse_hospitals
    )

def parse_hospitals(self, response):
    #here you have hospitals data
    .....
```